# Oracle SOA Human work flow hangs with attachment

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to debug an issue that started occurring in the test environment.

I have a Oracle SOA (11.1.1.6) composite with a BPEL that invokes a Human task. The Human task is very simple, I display the count and total from a file and attached the file.

Now when I attached a file over that is over 35K in size, the invocation of the human task appears to stall and never makes it to the BPM WorkList. This issue isn't happening in  production, but my concern is that it could appear there.

Any advice, pointers or directions as to where I can look to figure out why this is occurring?